# Select spans not in an anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors, selector

```
<span>Item 1</span>
<span>Item 2</span>
<a href="#"><span>Item 3</span></a>
<span>Item 4</span>
<a href="#"><span>Item 5</span></a>
<span>Item 6</span>
```

What king of a selector would I use to select the spans that aren't wrapped in an anchor tag (in this case items 1,2,4 and 6.

Comment: A few dif ways you could do it, one would be `.filter`, like: `$('span').filter(function(i){return $(this).parent('a').length})`

Comment: Thanks, this is close but this returns the spans with an anchor wrapper. What's the opposite of this?

Comment: @MattCoady $('span').filter(function(i){return !$(this).parent('a').length});

Comment: Yah my bad. I forgot the exclamation point.  Above me got it. As I said there's a half dozen or more ways. Even `.not`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery uses mainly css selectors and in css I don't think there's any "parent selector". However, you can use a combination of css selectors with the help of jquery to target the `span`s that are not child of an anchor like below...

```
$("span").not("a span");
```

```js
$(function(){
    $("span").not("a span").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Item 1</span>
<span>Item 2</span>
<a href="#"><span>Item 3</span></a>
<span>Item 4</span>
<a href="#"><span>Item 5</span></a>
<span>Item 6</span>
```

Comment: Oh, that's short and sweet. Perfect, thanks! I changed it to "a > span" to prevent any further reaching selection.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my approach

```
var sp = $('span');
var only = [];
for (var i = 0; i < sp.length; i++) {
    if ($(sp[i]).parent('a').length === 0) {
        only.push(sp[i]);
    }
}
console.log(only)
```

```js
var sp = $('span');
var only = [];
for (var i = 0; i < sp.length; i++) {
  if ($(sp[i]).parent('a').length === 0) {
    $(sp[i]).css('background', '#ccc');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Item 1</span>

<span>Item 2</span>

<a href="#"><span>Item 3</span></a>

<span>Item 4</span>

<a href="#"><span>Item 5</span></a>

<span>Item 6</span>
```